# Controller routing doesn't work always redirects to 404

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community, controllers, 404

So after looking through the first 2 pages of google search results I saw that it's quite a common problem nevertheless I couldn't find a solution that would work for me.

So the problem is that the routing doesn't seem to be working even though it seems for me that I've set everything up properly. Most of the solutions I found on google or on stackexchange were related to spelling mistakes in the code but I can't find any in mine after looking at it for good 3 hours or so.

for example if go to either one of these links magento just gives me 404 page

localhost/magento/index.php/helloworld

localhost/magento/index.php/helloworld/index

localhost/magento/index.php/helloworld/index/index

So my folder structure is

```
app
-code
--local
---Vhks
----Helloworld
-----Block
-----Helper
-----Model
-----controllers
------IndexController.php
-----etc
------config.xml
-----sql
```

My IndexController.php

```
<?php 

class Vhks_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        

    public function indexAction(){

        echo "Hello World";

    }
}
?>
```

and my config.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vhks_Helloworld>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vhks_Helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <vhks_helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Vhks_Helloworld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </vhks_helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and my /app/etc/modules/Vhks_Helloworld.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Vhks_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Vhks_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and my module shows up under System->Configuration->Advanced Disable Modules Output

Comment: You've used a different case, `vhks_helloworld` and `Vhks_Helloworld`

Comment: If you're talking about the <vhks_helloworld> node inside <routers> node in config.xml then it's not the problem, it can be whatever you want it to be, it's suggested to be lowercase module name, but it's still not a thing that would stop routes from working, anyways, I just tried changing it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: try to change node name <vhks_helloworld> by <helloworld> just after <routers> node and before </routers> node in config.xml

Comment: and don't put ?> tag at the end of php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, everything seems to be correct. However the problem may be because of following things.

- I can see a closing php tag in your controller file. It is not a good practice. Try to avoid it.`?>` is big NO NO in a php script only files such as controller, block classes, helper classes etc.
- Please check file permissions of your files. Give them proper permission
- I can see unwanted spaces in your `config.xml` file at the very beginning before `<?xml`. If it is there, try to remove it.
- Clear cache and try to load the page again. For this remove the folder `var/cache`.
- Last but not least, you need to put your application in developer mode and check whether system logs any error for you inside `var/log/exception.log` or `var/log/system.log`

Answer (score 3):

### Do you need to include the store code in the URL?

I was tearing my hair out over this same problem.

In my case, I finally realised it was because I'm running a multi-store environment with the store code included in the URL. So instead of:

localhost/magento/index.php/helloworld

I should have been using:

localhost/magento/index.php/en_gb/helloworld

Where "en_gb" was the store code.